# joda.time.DateTime deserialization error

Tags: java, json, datetime, serialization, deserialization

I tried to deserialize a class with a DateTime as attibute:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DateTimeSerializer;

class MyClass {

    private DateTime alertTimestamp;

    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
    public DateTime getAlertTimestamp() {
        return alertTimestamp;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
    public void setAlertTimestamp(DateTime now) {
        this.alertTimestamp = now;
    }

    //...
}
```

But when I try tro deserialize, I have this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
```

I use that to deserialize:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(jsonData, MyClass.class);
```

And an example of my  jsonData:

```
{    
    "name":"test",
    "alertTimestamp":       {"year":2014,"era":1,"dayOfMonth":24,"dayOfWeek":1,"dayOfYear":83,"weekOfWeekyear":13,"weekyear":2014,"monthOfYear":3,"yearOfEra":2014,"yearOfCentury":14,"centuryOfEra":20,"millisOfSecond":232,"millisOfDay":45143232,"secondOfMinute":23,"secondOfDay":45143,"minuteOfHour":32,"minuteOfDay":752,"hourOfDay":12,"zone":{"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"America/Los_Angeles"},"fixed":false,"id":"America/Los_Angeles"},"millis":1395689543232,"chronology":{"zone":{"uncachedZone":{"cachable":true,"fixed":false,"id":"America/Los_Angeles"},"fixed":false,"id":"America/Los_Angeles"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":false,"equalNow":true}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify `timestamp` vs `alertTimestamp`?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake

Comment: What JSON generator generated the JSON in `jsonData`? `DateTimeSerializer` does not serialize into that format.

Comment: According to [this source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.0.0-RC2/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/DateTimeDeserializer.java) the class `DateTimeDeserializer` has a public no-arg constructor. This arises the question if you have the proper import or appropriate jar-version?

Comment: @MenoHochschild [Version 2.3.0 doesn't.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/DateTimeDeserializer.java?av=f)

Comment: The data has been generated before I used the DataTimeSerialiser. I generated new data, now I have "alertTimestamp":1395775173517 but the exception is still there.

Comment: I don't have this constructor in my DateTimeDeserializer source

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@JsonDeserialize` expects a `JsonDeserializer` with a no-arg constructor. The most recent version of `DateTimeDeserializer` does not have such a constructor.

If you've fixed the format, ie. `alertTimestamp` should just be a timestamp, then you could simply register the `JodaModule` with the `ObjectMapper`. It will use `DateTimeDeserializer` internally for `DateTime` fields. You can get rid of the `@JsonDeserialize` annotations.

```
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

You'll need to add the `jackson-datatype-joda` library.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @arcone What would you like an example of?

Comment: I figured it out - it was a Spring response issue with DateTime.

Comment: I've encountered a bug in GlassFish that refuses me to register the `JodaModule` :-( Is there another way to apply the deserialization method?

Comment: @thomas.mc.work You'll need to register a custom deserializer for `DateTime` fields.

Comment: I've found out that it's possible to use an older version of the library `jackson-datatype-joda` (v2.4.6)