# Jackson, Retrofit, JodaTime deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, jodatime

I'm using those three libraries: retrofit, jackson and jodatime, and I'm trying somethings to deserialize my object when it comes from my rest api, but I could not figure out how to solve this, here goes the json returned by rest api:

```
{
    "establishment": "Gold Ball Confraria",
    "idCardPayment": 0,
    "paymentDate": "/Date(1461208761970+0000)/",
    "total": 10
}
```

and that is the class that I've tried to deserialize my object:

```
public class PaymentHistoryItemApiResult {

    @JsonProperty("total")
    private double totalValue;
    @JsonProperty("establishment")
    private String establishmentName;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private DateTime paymentDate;
    private long idCardPayment;

    public PaymentHistoryItemApiResult() {

    }

    public PaymentHistoryItemApiResult(double totalValue, String establishmentName, DateTime paymentDate, long idCardPayment) {
        this.totalValue = totalValue;
        this.establishmentName = establishmentName;
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
        this.idCardPayment = idCardPayment;
    }
... getters/setters

}
```

Api endpoint:

```
    @GET("User.svc/{idUser}/payment/history")
    Call<PaymentHistoryItemApiResult> getPaymentHistory(@Path("idUser") long idUser);
```

How it's been called from Unit Test:

```
@Test
public void getPaymentHistoryTest(){

    Response<PaymentHistoryItemApiResult> info = null;
    try {
        info = UserRequester.userRequester.getPaymentHistory(153).execute();

        PaymentHistoryItemApiResult res = info.body();
        Assert.assertNotNull(res);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
 at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@525b461a; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:251)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:269)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:477)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._findRootDeserializer(ObjectReader.java:1813)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1570)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1183)
    at retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:32)
    at retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonResponseBodyConverter.convert(JacksonResponseBodyConverter.java:23)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:116)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
    at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
    at br.com.soutsapp.user.souts.WCFClientTest.getPaymentHistoryTest(WCFClientTest.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer has no default (no arg) constructor
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.createInstance(ClassUtil.java:594)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.deserializerInstance(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:234)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findDeserializerFromAnnotation(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:1772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.constructSettableProperty(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:506)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:228)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:406)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:352)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
    ... 38 more
```

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Exception complains about DateTimeDeserializer not having a no-arg constructor. The constructor of DateTimeDeserializer expects a Class and a JacksonJodaDateFormat. The JsonDeserialize annotation has an optional "builder" parameter, maybe that can help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: @localhorst I'll try something using this `JacksonJodaDateFormat`, thanks

Comment: I was using jackson joda time module and everything simply worked, even without declaring deserializators

Answer (score 4):

### First View Analysis:

There are some issues in your code. That your provided time `"/Date(1461208761970+0000)/"` not looking familiar. You have some code issue also. That your constructor can not talk with joda constructor properly

### Root Cause:

Your issue:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer has no
>   default (no arg) constructor

is generates from your code:

```
 at br.com.soutsapp.user.souts.WCFClientTest.getPaymentHistoryTest(WCFClientTest.java:96)
```

### Issue Analysis:

To deserialize value to `org.joda.time.DateTime` you have to define `@JsonDeserialize` because Jackson cannot figure out what method/constructor use from `org.joda.time.DateTime` to initialize it from a string value.

### Solution - 1:

You need to use serialize as well as deserialize. You should check jar availability and should set to reading type as JSON.

**You can follow these 3 steps.**

1. You need to use serialize as well as deserialize. Your date patter should look like as JsonFormat.

Code will be

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateTimeDeserializer.class)
private DateTime paymentDate;
```

2. Make sure that you have on classpath `jackson-datatype-joda`.
3. Change SSM configuration to use JSON format by default (in
   defaultMemcachedClient definition):

   `<property name="defaultSerializationType" value="JSON" />`

### Resource Link:

https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached/issues/41

---

### Solution - 2:

You can add another constructor also. That may effect.

```
 public PaymentHistoryItemApiResult() {
        super();
   }
```

### Resource Link: Following 2 links containing more error analysis with solution

1. [Jackson Exceptions – Problems and Solutions](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception)
2. [Jackson – JsonMappingException (No serializer found for class)](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception)

---

### Another Solution:

If you don't want to use deserialize then you can follow details:

`@JsonDeserialize` expects a `JsonDeserializer` with a no-arg constructor. The most recent version of DateTimeDeserializer does not have such a constructor.

If you've fixed the format, ie. yourTimestamp should just be a timestamp, then you could simply register the `JodaModule` with the `ObjectMapper`. It will use DateTimeDeserializer internally for DateTime fields. **You can get rid of the @JsonDeserialize annotations.**

```
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

You'll need to add the `jackson-datatype-joda` library.

### Resource link:

1. [joda.time.DateTime deserialization error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643367/joda-time-datetime-deserialization-error)

### [For null value serialization and deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404703/how-to-deserialize-joda-datetime-using-jackson-with-jersey-2-client-in-spring-mv)

If you don't want to serialize null values, you can use the following setting during serialization:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
```

For deserialization Jackson should ideally be able to handle null values in the serialized output.

Credit goes to @[jackall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428558/jackall)

or you can use annotations also in your class.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

Comment: I guess it might be worth mentioning how to add the objectMapper to retrofit service. 
            
       .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper))

Answer (score 1):

I use my custom deserialize:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private DateTime expiryTimeFirebaseCustomAccessToken;
```

with class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.FormatConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.DateTimeDeserializer;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

/**
 * Created by rudi on 3/28/18.
 */

public class MyDateTimeDeserializer extends DateTimeDeserializer {

    public MyDateTimeDeserializer() {
        super(DateTime.class, FormatConfig.DEFAULT_DATETIME_PARSER);
    }

    public MyDateTimeDeserializer(Class<?> cls, JacksonJodaDateFormat format) {
        super(cls, format);
    }

}
```

and it's works for me... Maybe it can contribute

Answer (score -1):

Just use https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda. It works out of the box and you don't have to use additional annotations to serialize/deserialize datetime into joda time objects.

Comment: Can that Joda module deserialize `/Date(1461208761970+0000)/`? I've never seen this format.

Comment: And doesn't their `DateTimeDeserializer` come from that library anyway?

Comment: IDK what kind of format is that. Never use nor saw it before.